# How to change the src attribute of <img> in .vue files with webpack and vue-loader?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-loader, webpack-3

I have a vue.js (version 2.4.4) application built with webpack (version 3.6.0) and vue-loader (version 13.0.5).

In the .vue files, I need to modify the url contained in the src attribute of the `<img>` tags according to the environment of my application.

- In the development environment, the images must come from the
  application folder, with a relative path: "/src/images/exemple.png"
- In the production environment, the images must come from a cdn, with
  an absolute path: "https://my-cdn.net/images/exemple.png"

In the "webpack.config.js" file, I already differentiate the different environments using "process.env.NODE_ENV", like this:

```
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev';
```

But I don't know how to modify the src attribute of the img tags in my .vue files with vue-loader (or with something else).

For information, here is the definition of the vue-loader in the "webpack.config.js" file:

```
{
  test: /\.vue$/,
  loader: 'vue-loader',
  options: {
    loaders: {
      'scss': [
        'vue-style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'sass-loader'
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Piggybacking off of [@Michael Levy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59416472/4096078)'s answer:

I am currently having this issue with Vue 3, @vue/cli 4.5.10, and webpack. I've solved it after much research.

Webpack configurations go into `vue.config.js`, where there is a lot of abstraction. To fine tune control, you can use [chain webpack configs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#chaining-advanced). To help you, use `Vue Inspect`  when you are trying to access specific loaders via chaining.

```sh
$ vue inspect > output.js
```

That will give you a nice list of all the loaders that vue-cli is using.

For example - to modify webpack image options within `vue.config.js`, you can use `vue inspect > output.js`, search the `output.js` file, and discover the loader that's managing images.

Which is: `/* config.module.rule('images').use('url-loader') */`

To answer the question - in your `vue.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
      .rule("images")
      .use("url-loader")
      .tap((options) => {

        options.name = "images/[name].[ext]";
        options.publicPath = isDev ? __webpack_public_path__ : 'https://my-cdn.net/';

        return options;
      });
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`Vue-loader` is preconfigured to handle `src` attributes in Vue single file components as you can [see here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html). So for example `<img src="../image.png">` in the template is transformed into:

```js
createElement('img', {
  attrs: {
    src: require('../image.png') // this is now a module request
  }
})
```

What Webpack do with this `require` depends on configured loaders. Usual there is a [`file-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader) configured. It looks like this (from project generated by Vue CLI + simplified):

```js
module: { 
  rules: [
    {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp)(\?.*)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'img/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
  ]
}
```

Loader is responsible for copying your file into `dist` directory and returning public URI, which will be inserted into `src` attribute.

So what you want can be configured here, by specifying right [options](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/#options). For example:

```js
options: {
  name: 'images/[name].[ext]'
  publicPath: isDev ? __webpack_public_path__ : 'https://my-cdn.net/'
}
```

Just take content of `dist/images` directory after the build and deploy it so it is accessible by `https://my-cdn.net/images` and it should work....

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alias for`/src/images` and alter the url at transpile time based on the environment:

```
{
//..
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '/src/images': isDev ? '/src/images' : process.env.IMAGE_CDN + '/images'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not think this is correct answer. Aliases are for resolution only (when webpack is looking for all dependencies)....

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle this would be to use [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to create a global variable that each of your images reference.

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    console.log('\n')
    console.log('Setting global variables:')
    console.log(`__YOUR_GLOBAL_CONSTANT__: ${JSON.stringify(process.env.YOUR_GLOBAL_CONSTANT)}`)
    console.log('\n')

    config
      .plugin('provide')
      .use(require('webpack').DefinePlugin, [{
        __YOUR_GLOBAL_CONSTANT__: JSON.stringify(process.env.YOUR_GLOBAL_CONSTANT)
      }])
  }
}
```

The example above is utilizing a [`vue.config.js` file](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config), but the strategy should be pretty similar. Also, if you're using something like eslint, you'll need to specify the variable in the globals section as readonly.